# Check if a give port is included in output, if it is run another command

Tags: bash

I have a `commandb`:
`printf '%s' "${PORTS[0]}"; printf ',%s' "${PORTS[@]:1}"`

That lists ports from another command that output of `commandb` looks like:

```
2200,800,8000
```

These ports are stored in a file name `res.txt`

I want to check if `commandb` has a specific port of `8000`, if it does, I want to run a `commandc`, otherwise do nothing.

How can I achieve this in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -w` to specify a word boundary:

```
$ grep -qw '8000' res.txt && echo 'hello world'
hello world
```

The `-q` option just prevents `grep` from printing the results so you can simply act on the exit code.  Without the `-w` option you would get a successful result from `80` as it is contained within `800` and `8000`:

```
$ grep -q '80' res.txt && echo 'hello world'; echo $?
hello world
0
$ grep -qw '80' res.txt && echo 'hello world'; echo $?
1
```

In order to check for the existence of multiple ports you can do the following:

```
if grep -qw -e '8000' -e '80' res.txt; then
    do something
fi
```

Comment: can you check for multiple ports like 80 and 8080 with -qw '80' || '8080' ?

Comment: Do you want to know if both exist or if one or the other exists?

Comment: one or other please.

Comment: @johnjones: Does my update help?

Comment: you should be able to give `grep` multiple patterns to match against, e.g. `echo '123,456,789' | grep -w -e 123 -e 111` should report a match and print the line